# Async trait methods with associated return type and dynamic dispatch

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I need to handle async data streams from several different sources which should all be parsed into some normalized format.

Ideally I would like to:

- Write a handler for each source that implements some `Handler` trait so downstream callers can interact with the data streams and be agnostic with respect to the underlying implementation.
- Have some function which can return a `Box<dyn Handler>` given a key since there are a limited/predictable number of sources for which `Handler` is implemented.

I've tried something like the following using `#[async_trait]` but I can't get it to compile, mostly with error "the trait `Handler` cannot be made into an object".

Is there a better/more idiomatic way to approach this problem?

```
use async_trait; // 0.1.52
use tokio; // 1.15.0

#[async_trait::async_trait]
trait Handler{
    type Output;
    
    async fn connect()->Self::Output;

    async fn read_parse(&self)->Vec<i32>;

    async fn run(&self) {
        for _ in 0..5 {
            self.read_parse().await;
        }
    }
    
}

struct FooHandler;

#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl Handler for FooHandler {
    type Output = FooHandler;
    
    async fn connect() -> Self::Output {
        tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
        FooHandler{}
    }
    
    async fn read_parse(&self)->Vec<i32> {
        tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
        vec![1, 2, 3]
    }
}

struct BarHandler;

#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl Handler for BarHandler {
    type Output = BarHandler;
    
    async fn connect() -> Self::Output {
        tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
        BarHandler{}
    }
    
    async fn read_parse(&self)->Vec<i32> {
        tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
        vec![1, 2, 3]
    }
}


async fn get_handler(name:&str)->Option<Box<dyn Handler>> {
    match name {
        "FOO"=>Some(Box::new(FooHandler::connect().await)),
        "BAR"=>Some(Box::new(BarHandler::connect().await)),
        _=>None
    }
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let handler = get_handler("FOO").await.unwrap();
    handler.run().await;
}
```

EDIT:

Per the answer from cameron1024 I was able to get the following to work:

```
use async_trait; // 0.1.52
use tokio; // 1.15.0

#[async_trait::async_trait]
trait Handler: Sync {
    
    async fn connect()->Self
    where
        Self: Sized;
        
    async fn read_parse(&self)->Vec<i32>;

    async fn run(&self) {
        for _ in 0..5 {
            let res = self.read_parse().await;
            println!("{:?}", res);
        }
    }
    
}

struct FooHandler;

#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl Handler for FooHandler {
    
    async fn connect() -> Self {
        tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
        println!("connected");
        FooHandler{}
    }
    
    async fn read_parse(&self)->Vec<i32> {
        tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        vec![1, 2, 3]
    }
}

async fn get_handler(name: &str)->Option<Box<dyn Handler>> {
    match name {
        "FOO"=>Some(Box::new(FooHandler::connect().await)),
        _=>None
    }
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // let handler = FooHandler::connect().await;
    let handler = get_handler("FOO").await.unwrap();
    handler.run().await;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues here.

First, for a async trait to have default implementations, it requires that the trait itself have `Send` or `Sync` (depending on the receiver type) as a supertrait (there is a brief explanation in the "dyn traits" section of the readme for the crate: https://docs.rs/async-trait/latest/async_trait/)

Second the `connect` function is not object safe, because its return type is an associated function. This is nothing to do with async-ness, it's an object safety concern. This simplified example has the same issue:

```rust
fn main() {
   let x: Box<dyn Foo<Bar = ()>> = Box::new(());
}

trait Foo {
    type Bar;

    fn connect() -> Self::Bar;
}

impl Foo for () {
    type Bar = ();

    fn new() -> Self::Bar {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

However, you're unlikely to want to invoke `connect` on a trait object, since it has no `self` parameter. Instead, you can opt that specific function out of the trait object by adding the `Self: Sized` constraint to `connect`.

You can then create a trait object, but `connect` won't be available.